# redirect to renderURL in a MVCPortlet not working

Tags: forms, liferay, portlet

I am building a MVCPortlet Liferay 6.2 portlet. I have a form with 2 buttons. First button validates the form (submit). The second one redirects to a jsp. I have a difficulty to make it work:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="mainSubmit" var="mainSubmitURL"></portlet:actionURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="viewLogsURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/jsp/logs.jsp"/> 
</portlet:renderURL>

<form ... action="<%=mainSubmitURL%>">
...
<div class="controls-row  ">
             <label class="span1"   ></label>
             <input class="span2 btn " type="submit" value="Submit Form" > 
             <label class="span4"   ></label>
             <input  class="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
        </div>
</form>
```

First button works fine but second button does not redirect to viewLogsURL.

If I replace:

```
<input  class="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
```

with:

```
<buttonclass="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
```

then the button also makes a submits the form url (mainSubmitURL) instead of the button URL (viewLogsURL).

And if I use:

```
     <aui:button  class="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
```

This actually performs the correct redirection but I would like to avoid using it as it generates some css style issues and some filtering-proxy issues that I don't have with  or .
So I would rather use  or  if possible (and I m pretty sure it is).

I also tried to change :

```
<portlet:renderURL var="viewLogsURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/jsp/logs.jsp"/> 
</portlet:renderURL>
```

with:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="viewLogsURL">
        <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsp/logs.jsp"/> 
</portlet:renderURL>
```

No chance...

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML `onclick` attribute is used to execute JavaScript code, when the element is clicked. The value must be valid JavaScript code, not a URL. You've probably mistaken it with `<a href='url'>...</a>` attribute.

That's a basic HTML concept - see for example [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) description for more details.

To make the redirect work, you can set the redirect URL as the current location:

```
<input class="span2 btn" onClick="location.href = '<%= viewLogsURL.toString() %>'" value="View Logs"/>
```

Or call a JavaScript function instead:

```
<input class="span2 btn" onClick="<portlet:namespace/>doRedirect()" value="View Logs"/>

<script>
    function <portlet:namespace/>doRedirect() {
        location.href = '<%= viewLogsURL.toString() %>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Diky moc, Thank you very much for your help Tomas, it works like a charm for me :)